# Set a reminder/timer on an Alexa Custom Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'd like an alarm to go off based on my custom alexa skill. Is it possible to set a timer similar to manually asking Alexa to set a timer through a skill?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not currently possible, but Amazon is certainly are of developers desire for this.

Your skill sends responses to the user within the context of a request - it can't initiate new output minutes later.

You might be able to do something hacky with a very long response or with the new audio streaming capability but I don't think that would get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Any change on this?

Comment: Alexa allows only Synchronous response as of now. There is a pending feature request on the same. Vote and follow up with the status at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349022/set-a-reminder-timer-on-an-alexa-custom-skill